# Why the output is not ordered by alphabetical way when I use factor() without setting levels?

Tags: r

This is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
x <- c("Jan","Aug", "Feb")
sort(x)
#> [1] "Aug" "Feb" "Jan"
factor(x)
#> [1] Jan Aug Feb
#> Levels: Aug Feb Jan
```

I know sort function will order x in an alphabetical way. And I think if I just factor(x) but don't pass any levels into it, it will still order x in an alphabetical way (a way of default). But it turns out to be the results as shown in code above. I mean, why the result is not ordered by alphabetical way? Thanks many in advance!

Comment: because `factor` does not change the order, it converts `x` to `factor` with levels in alphabetical order.

Comment: But why output shows the levels are ordered by alphabetical way? Since it shows the levels is in alphabetical way, shouldn't it be ordered by this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `levels` and the order in which `factor`s are printed has no relation. `factor` does not change the order of the vector. `levels` of `factors` usually are in an alphabetical way unless they are explicitly mentioned. See for example,

```
let <- letters[1:10]
factor(let)
#[1] a b c d e f g h i j
#Levels: a b c d e f g h i j
```

Setting levels explicitly reversing the levels.

```
factor(let, levels = rev(let))
# [1] a b c d e f g h i j
#Levels: j i h g f e d c b a
```

Assign random levels.

```
set.seed(123)
factor(let, levels = sample(let))
#[1] a b c d e f g h i j
#Levels: c j b h f i a g e d
```

As we can see in all the cases the `levels` are different but irrespective of `levels` the way factors are printed do not change because `factor` do not change the order.

Comment: I got that! Thank you!